# how to create a context object in google cloud run for firebase

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to create a context object, so that I can connect to firestore from cloud run, however, all the examples I find on the net basically say I need a context objects, examples I find online usually look like this:

```
        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "projectID")
        if err != nil {
            fail(w, err.Error())
            // TODO: Handle error.
        }
```

You can find these examples in places like this one:
https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#example-NewClient
Nowhere in this example is there an explanation of where to find the context object.

so I just get this error:

```
undefined: context
```

I think the documentation is just too confusing.

Comment: I just found another google example, here the context is imported as plainly "context",:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/auth/snippets.go

 however, when one goes directly into the folder where the context thing should be defined, it turns out there is no "context" file, this stuff is crippled by design.

Comment: This is practically the first thing you learn in Go. Please take the [Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, you need to import packages. For this statement `ctx := context.Background()` add to the top of your source file `import "context"` or merge with your existing import set.

Like most languages, the more experience you have the more the language makes sense and you just know what to do. Most languages are the same. In C/C++ you have the `include` statement, C# the `using` statement, in Python the `import` statement, etc.

Google has a large package of examples for using Go and Google Cloud Platform:

[Google Cloud Examples in Go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/archive/master.zip)

I wrote an article that documents my 30-day journey to learn Go and Google Cloud Platform.

[Google Cloud and Go – My Journey to Learn a new Language in 30 days](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-and-go-my-journey-to-learn-a-new-language-in-30-days/)

Comment: I thank you for your answer, I kinda expected google’s example to be runnable outside of their “cloud functions” environment, so I kinda wanted to simply run it locally, however the problem is that in the docs it is not clear where to find the context file or in which library it is defined. one could even say they are telling their customers that everything is easy when in reality there is a lot of hidden code and they are not making it easy for people to access firebase outside of their firebase functions context where the context is a free global variable already defined.

Comment: if you open the link you will see the context file is intentionally missing, because google likes go devs to suffer.

Comment: Your comment is valid for any language. Google assumes that you know how to program in a language. Stuff like import statements, packages, etc are the very first items to learn on Go. If Google overloaded their documentation with very beginner stuff, those that know the language would get tired of the repetition. API documentation should show how to use the API, not how to use the language. However, opinions do vary on this matter.

Comment: @FelipeValdes quite disagree with that. Not just google, every company/organization that provide documentation for their 3rd parties library will always assume that the one who read the doc already know at least "how to speak the language". learn the basic of go it self before trying to understand the 3rd party

Comment: Ok, I'll go back to school.

Comment: Plus, if you use standard tools, the imports will be added automatically for you, so explicitly documenting them is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `r.Context()` of http.Request object in the request handler instead of initializing a new detached context like context.Background().

The main purpose of contexts is to propagate them, and in Cloud Run you always process requests, so if you pass the request’s context, it’s the right thing to do.

I think in your case, “context” package is not imported. Make sure to use go 1.11+ in your Dockerfile and say:

```
import “context”
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the plethora of 3 lines of code examples that are hard for beginners, and the lack of complete working examples online, like myself, here is a full working example, which is kinda what I needed when I started this task, I hope this helps anybody in the future.

```
package main
import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore" // https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    "context"                       // https://blog.golang.org/context
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)
func fail(w http.ResponseWriter, msg string) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "fail:"+msg)
    log.Println("fail:" + msg)
}

// State example code
type State struct {
    Capital    string  `firestore:"capital"`
    Population float64 `firestore:"pop"` // in millions
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        override := make(map[string]interface{})

        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "YOURPID")// set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var
        if err != nil {
            fail(w, err.Error())
            return
        }

        states := client.Collection("States")
        ny := states.Doc("NewYork")
        wr, err := ny.Create(ctx, State{
            Capital:    "Albany",
            Population: 19.8,
        })
        fmt.Println(wr)

    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8082", nil))
}
```